# Почему не совпадает значение получаемое в python chisquare с данными из таблицы распределения хи-квадрата?

Tags: python, статистика, scipy

Необходимо имея набор чисел найти p-значение через хи-квадрат.
Вот такой код:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

c = chisquare([10,4,7,5],ddof=[0,1,2,3])

print(c)
```

В результате программа выдает:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=3.2307692307692308, pvalue=array([ 0.35739509,  0.19881419,  0.07226674,         nan]))
```

Сверяю с таблицами распределения хи-квадрата - там при тех же значения хи-квадрата и степени свободы совершенно другие p-значения.
Почему так?

Comment: Приведите также значения из справочника с точным указанием всех параметров и самое главное - названий параметров. P-value может означать что угодно в зависимости от автора и контекста, напишите человеческое название этого параметра (это значение вероятности?).

Comment: Приведите ожидаемые значения. Вы пробовали изменять или не указывать значение(я) `ddof`?

Comment: Да, p-value это значение вероятности. Например для степени свободы=1 (ddof=0) если смотреть по таблице то p-value = 0.01

Comment: @LOGA, значение pvalue меняется в зависимости от значений первого  аргумента (`Observed frequencies in each category`) - я не представляю как можно составить такую таблицу заранее...

Comment: @LOGA, ddof - это коррекция степеней свободы. Функция считает значение вероятности со степенью равной k - 1 - ddof, где k - количество наблюдений. Я проверил ваши значения в [таблице распределения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Квантили_распределения_хи-квадрат) и все совпадает. В данном случае ([но далеко не всегда](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29825/what-is-the-relationship-between-quantile-functions-and-p-values)) альфа = 1 - p-value.